# How do I tell a variable to be a specific custom type for a class function in PHP

Tags: php

When has a class has a function with a custom type, how do you initiate the variable so it is the correct type?

```
class test {
public function __construct(EmailService $emailService) 
    {
        $this->$emailService = $emailService;
    }
}

$emailService = "gmail";

$test = new test($emailService);
```

With the code like this, it will error out because its the wrong type, how do I initiate the variable so it will be of type EmailService?

Comment: `how do I initiate the variable so it will be of type EmailService`...hint: the same kind of way you are initiating $test to be of type "test"...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of that class.

```
$emailService = new EmailService("gmail");
$test = new test($emailService);
```